# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline calling Method stages

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

**Goal**

I'm trying to create multiple docker images that have slightly different configurations, these will form the basis of different builds further down stream. To avoid code duplication, I'm trying to use a method inside my Declarative pipeline.

**Problem**

I can't work out how to have a method that has multiple `stages {}` inside of it.

**Example**

```
pipeline{
  agent any


  stages{
    stage('Create Images'){
      parallel {
        stage('Image Foo'){
          environment{
            dockerImage=''
          }
          stages{
            stage("Build image"){
              steps{
                scripted{
                  dockerImage=docker.build(...)
                }
              }
            }
            stage("Configure image"){
              configImage(dockerImage)
            }
            stage('Push to artifactory'){
              steps{
                scripted{
                  dockerImage.push()
                  dockerImage.push("latest")
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        stage('Image Bar'){
          environment{
            dockerImage=''
          }
          stages{
            stage("Build image"){
              steps{
                scripted{
                  dockerImage=docker.build(...)
                }
              }
            }
            stage("Configure image"){
              configImage(dockerImage)
            }
            stage('Push to artifactory'){
              steps{
                scripted{
                  dockerImage.push()
                  dockerImage.push("latest")
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void configImage(dockerImage){
  stages{
    stage("Grab some files"){
      steps{
        echo "I'm getting some files"
      }
    }
    stage("Install some stuff"){
      steps{
        echo "Install all the things"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can re-architect this so the method has no stages inside of it and merely executes the required logic. Also, the objectives here are likely made too granular, so the architecture of the pipeline has too many stages mapped to objectives. In either case, a re-architecture of the pipeline will optimize and fix the issue.

Comment: @MattSchuchard The method in my actual code base contains 6 stages. I've always preferred things to be quite verbose \ modular. That being said, it may well be smarter to in a bash script and execute it inside the container. Though I really wanted leverage the stages.